# Laravel: Show HTML Code and Laravel Syntax from Database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

in my App I have a table (cats) with 30 categories. The Table "cats" has a name and code field. Every Category needs different forms. To be more flexible and to make the code simpler, I am saving the HTML Code for the different forms directly into the Database.

I am able to fetch the content with:

```
{!! $cats->code !!}
```

The Content of the DB Field:

```
<label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">
```

Well, with that simple code, everything runs fine, the HTML Syntax will be shown.

Now I tried with that Code, but this is not working. I think it could be, because I am mixing html with laravel syntax...

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve this issue?

Kind Regards

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. Your blade views are parsed to HTML with PHP before any code is run. So Laravel will eventually just echo the blade code, but it is not getting parsed at that stage of your app.

A solution would be to wrap everything in PHP and use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to have dynamic content stored in the database. This makes it a little bit more of an effort, but it is certainly possible.